# Why are there C++ algorithms defined specially for uninitialized memory?

Tags: c++

Why do we need [special algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm#Operations_on_uninitialized_memory) to write to uninitialized (but allocated) memory? Won't the normal [modifying algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm#Modifying_sequence_operations) do? Or does *uninitialized* memory mean something different from what the name itself conveys?

Comment: You're looking at the right documentation, but if you go a little deeper you can see sample implementations for the functions. These are often very enlightening. For example, [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy#Possible_implementation) vs [std::uninitialized_copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_copy#Possible_implementation)

Answer (score 8):

Take `std::copy` and `std::uninitialized_copy` for a range of `std::string`s.

Regular `copy` will assume there already exists a string there.  The copy assignment operator of string will try to use any existing space in the string if possible for the copy.

However, if there wasn't already a string there, as in the case of an uninitialized memory, the copy assignment operator will access garbage memory and behavior is undefined.

Uninitialized copy on the other hand will *create* the string there instead of assigning to it, so it can be used in a memory that does not already have a string in it.

Essentially, the regular versions will have a `*it = value;` in them, and uninitialized versions will have something like a `new (&(*it)) T(value);`.

Comment: It isn't really about reusing memory or any kind of optimization. The algorithms do fundamentally different things. One copy assigns to the output iterator and the other placement `new`s the copied object.

Comment: Right, I just thought a concrete example makes it easier to understand for non-experts.

Comment: That's brushing over quite a few crucial tricky details, but at least the general idea is right. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_copy for an implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It's the difference between construction and assignment:

```
struct foo { /* whatever */ };
foo f;

unsigned char buf[sizeof foo];
foo *foo_ptr = (foo*) buf;
*foo_ptr = f; // undefined behavior; *foo_ptr does not point at a valid object
new (foo_ptr) foo; // okay; initializes raw memory
*foo_ptr = f; // okay; assignment to an existing object
```

Comment: I think it's not UB if foo is trivially copyable?

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka -- maybe; that "whatever" might be a bit too weak. But the point still stands.

Answer (score 2):

It is essentially about the *object lifecycle*.

After memory is allocated, it must be initialized by running the class' constructor. When the object is finished with, the class' destructor must be run.

The standard *algorithms* assume they are always accessing initialized memory and so objects can be created, copied, swapped and moved and deleted etc... based on that assumption.

When dealing with *uninitialized memory* however, the algorithms have to make sure they do not run a destructor on memory that was never initialized with the constructor. They have to avoid moving and swapping with non-existent objects by initializing the memory first when needed etc...

They have to deal with the extra step in the *object lifecycle* (initialization) that is unnecessary with already initialized memory.

Comment: _"[...] it must be initialized by running the class' constructor."_ - note that an object's lifetime _can_ begin even if no constructor of the class has been invoked, as per [\[dcl.init.general\]/19](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#19). The key for start of lifetime is that the object's initialization _shall be complete_ (and [whatever that means w.r.t. two-phased initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67991209) is another topic) rather than one of its constructors running to completion.