# Why is the statically initialization of an object definitely zero?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider this example in [basic.start.static#2], which has a more detail interpretation in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

```cpp
inline double fd() { return 1.0; }
extern double d1;
double d2 = d1;   // unspecified:
                  // dynamically initialized to 0.0 if d1 is dynamically initialized, or
                  // dynamically initialized to 1.0 if d1 is statically initialized, or
                  // statically initialized to 0.0 (because that would be its value
                  // if both variables were dynamically initialized)
double d1 = fd(); // may be initialized statically or dynamically to 1.0
```

For the first two remarks about dynamic initialization of `d2`, there is no doubt here. However, it says the static initialization of `d2` is `0.0`, I cannot figure out the reason. Since the standard didn't specify the **order** of the static initialization. In other words, If `d1` is used to statically initialize `d2`, why is the value of `d1` at this point definitely zero? The standard only says

> If constant initialization is not performed, a variable with static storage duration ([basic.stc.static]) or thread storage duration ([basic.stc.thread]) is zero-initialized ([dcl.init]). Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called static initialization; all other initialization is dynamic initialization. All static initialization strongly happens before ([intro.races]) any dynamic initialization.

Comment: Note that [this non-normative note](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.static#note-2) has been updated (at some point) to now say "unspecified: either statically initialized to 0.0 or dynamically initialized to 0.0 if d1 is dynamically initialized, or 1.0 otherwise", which make it clearer that the example refers to the state where the static initialization "merely zero-initialized". But these are muddy non-normative waters, as was recently discussed [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67991209).

Comment: @dfrib Yes, I also suspect that the wording "the static version of the initialization"in the second bullet of [basic.start.static] p3 refers to "zero-initialization" rather than constant initialization.

Comment: Yes. I'm guessing "static" is used instead of "zero" to emphasize that the case where both variables undergo dynamic initialization _implies_ that there is no constant initialization taking place, meaning static initialization is only zero initialization.

Comment: @dfrib If the intent is "zero-initialization", why it does not directly say: *the **zero-initialization** produces the same value in the initialized variable as would be produced by the dynamic initialization if all variables not required to be initialized statically were initialized dynamically.* After all, static initialization version comprises zero-initialization and constant initialization.

Comment: @dfrib However, even if we rule the second bullet like that. It also has the same problem, if we take the dynamic initialization for `d2` that initialized from `d1` as the static initialization version, what's the value of `d1` at this point? It still depends on the value of `d1`.

Comment: From the previous discussion around lifetimes on this topic (the Q&A I linked to above) I got the feeling of consensus around this being 1) a corner case in the standard, however still 2) somewhat underspecified. In the lifetimes discussion the question was focused on "could d2 even legally use a partially initialized d1; has the lifetime of d1 started or not d1 is yet to be dynaically initialized?". I think the root confusion is the same, though: underspecification and only a non-normative text (or two) to fall back on.

Comment: ... This particular example could probably be made more clear using e.g. "zero-initialization" instead of "static initialization which is implied to be only zero-initialization", but before that it would be good to really sort out the lifetimes issue (linked to Q&A), as the whole example relies on using something (d2 here) to initialize something else (d1 here) possibly before the lifetime of the something (d2) has started, which would imply UB (probably not intended nor implemented as such by implementors).

Comment: @dfrib David, I have issued this [problem](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/4800). You can freely leave your thoughts there. I think I phrased my thoughts more clearly in there.

Comment: @dfrib For the lifetime question, My opinion is that zero-initialization **does not** begin the lifetime of the object. Since *The lifetime of an object or reference is a **runtime property** of the object or reference.* zero-initialization, which could be said it is at a compile time.

Answer (score 0):

[[basic.start.static]/3:](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.start.static#3)

> An implementation is permitted to perform the initialization of a
> variable with static or thread storage duration as a static
> initialization even if such initialization is not required to be done
> statically, provided that
>
> - the dynamic version of the initialization does not change the value of any other object of static or thread storage duration prior to its
>   initialization, and
> - **the static version of the initialization produces the same value in the initialized variable as would be produced by the dynamic
>   initialization if all variables not required to be initialized
>   statically were initialized dynamically.**

You know that if `d1` and `d2` are both initialized dynamically, then `d1` is initialized to 0, so if `d1` is statically initialized, it should be initialized to 0.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm exactly saying? The remark says `d2` is statically initialized by `d1`, however, at this point why is the value of `d1` definitely zero? In other words, the order of the  static initialization of these two variables are not specified by the standard.

Comment: @xmh0511 It does not matter what the value of `d1` is. The rule I quoted describe the *result* of the initialization, not the *process* of the initialization.

Comment: I agree on the value would be 0 if d1 and d2 are both initialized dynamically since their zero-initialization is occurred prior to their dynamic initialization. However, the emphasized rule requires the static initialization of `d2` should be 0 then it can be statically initialized. I'm asking why is the value of `d1` the declaration of `d2` zero?

Comment: "It does not matter what the value of d1 is" Why? **the static version of the initialization produces the same value in the initialized variable as...**, In other words, the static version of `d2` initialized from `d1` should be zero. It didn't say *the **zero-initialization** produces the same value in the initialized variable as...*

Comment: @xmh0511 The rule describes the result of the initialization (what final value `d2` should be), so why does the process (what the value of `d1` is) matter?

Comment: I see the difference in understanding between you and me. You construe "provide that" as a "declarative sentence". Instead, I construe "provide that" as "if". Consider the first bullet, it seems it is "if". Only these conditions are satisfied will the dynamic initialization is processed to static initialization.

Comment: @xmh0511 I don't see any difference. If an implementation does not statically initialize `d2` with 0, it violates this rule. So, as a result, a confirming implementation must initialize `d2` with 0 if it wants to initialize it statically.

Comment: The "conditions" are certainly different from what we say they should be. The dynamic initialization of `d2` is zero, if the bullets after "provide that" are conditions, that means only if the static version of initialization of `d2` should be zero, then the condition is true. see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization, it says *if the following conditions are both true*. Do you think "the result is true" is equivalent to "if the result is true"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235813/discussion-between-xskxzr-and-xmh0511).

Comment: Given this example `double d1 = fd(); double d2 = d1;`. Do you think `d2` can be statically intialized to `1.0`?