# Is there specification defining intermediate value of a static global variable initialized by a function?

Tags: c++

Can you please point at the specification of the C++ language with regards to this behavior?

Assume the following code:

```cpp
static bool variable = Function();
```

What is the value of `variable` before `Function` runs? Is it undefined behavior or does `variable` has defined value?

(in case you wonder when would that be possible, you could have another library initializing a global/static with dependencies on another library that relies on static)

If the answer is "undefined behavior", is there a way to make it defined? If we tell the compiler to store `variable` in the zero initialized area, would that change things?

[edit]:

The best answer for now seems to have been [HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat)'s comment:

> The answer seems to be "it's initially zeroed, but whether reading the zero is UB is moot"

Which makes me assume that nobody found a specification paragraph explaining that.

Comment: Order of initialisations depends on order of linking. The main rule is not to have such tricky dependencies. At least statics are initialised to 0/NULL.

Comment: Please read about the [“static initialization order ‘fiasco’”](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [If a global variable is initialized twice (statically, then dynamically), which initialization starts its lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67991209/2752075). The answer seems to be "it's initially zeroed, but whether reading the zero is UB is moot".

Comment: Why do you need to know if the value is defined, undefined, **indeterminate** or something else? What problem is that knowledge supposed to solve?

Comment: @G.M. This is unrelated to the question.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005685/c-static-initialization-order

Comment: The real answer is don't use static globals, certainly not like this... now someone changes Function to rely on another static variable and you are in deep trouble : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof. When you need shared state between software parts make explicit interfaces, e.g. use dependency injection

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès And neither is this. OP has only one variable.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Only one variable we can see ;)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat if he has only one static variable, then there is no problem, isn't it?

Comment: This is why we ask for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also see [When are static and global variables initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783210/when-are-static-and-global-variables-initialized)

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès ...Yeah, I should've worded it differently. Yes, you can observe the difference only from a second static variable. But the linked question doesn't explain what the value of a not-yet-initialized variable is.

Comment: @OP Side note, Another option is to use `bool get_constant() { static bool value = Function(); return value(); }` this you can split into a function declaration in a shared header file and a definition in one translation unit. The boolean will then be initialized on first use (and will not depend on linking order). Or have a look at `inline constexpr` and immediately invoked (constexpr) lambdas. Maybe those apply to you too (assuming function doesn't do any runtime stuff).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks for your comment. I have observed it to be zero too in clang/gcc trunk for both ARM64 and x86_64 architectures. If this behavior is not in the spec than it is not to be relied on.

Comment: @FelipeLavratti Global variable are guaranteed to be zeroed. Though do note [static order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

Comment: @user12002570 can you point me at the spec?

Comment: @FelipeLavratti Sure, refer to [Non-local variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables). Equivalent description is in the standard document also that I am not linking here. But the above [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables) should solve the issue.

Answer (score -4):

Any variable that's not initialized will the contents of the memory where it's defined, aka undefined.
But in this initialization you are doing both define, and initialize, so it will have the value returned by the function.

But your code won't work in C99 because static variables have to be initialize with constants. You can put a 0 or NULL there, and the initialize somewhere else...

With the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int val() {
  return 1;
}


static int variable = val();

void main() {
 printf("%d", variable);
}
```

You will get

```
main.c:8:23: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
```

static int variable = val();

Comment: Now my downvote but the question is about C++. Your answer seem to be only about C.

Comment: It's possible to access the variable before its initializer runs (from an initializer of a different global variable), and global variables are zeroed by default, instead of having indeterminate values.